# Prevent or avoid Multiple clicks in Android app (Kotlin Language)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, onclick

**How to prevent user from doing multiple clicks on a button??.**

**Actual problem:** if user keep clicking on the button very quickly. Button click execute my api call multiple times.

**Applied Solution Not Work:** Even if you tried to disable the button directly after onClick(), still there is a probability to have multiple click happened.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solving Android multiple clicks problem — Kotlin**

I searched the community and found amazing solution like creating a custom click listener that will preserve the last click time and prevent clicking for a specific period
But — as a big fan of Kotlin — I was thinking to have something to use very smoothly using the power of lambdas and closures.
So I came up with this implementation, hope to help you

**Step 1 : Create class with name SafeClickListener.kt**

```
class SafeClickListener(

private var defaultInterval: Int = 1000,
private val onSafeCLick: (View) -> Unit
 ) : View.OnClickListener {
private var lastTimeClicked: Long = 0
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTimeClicked < defaultInterval) {
        return
    }
    lastTimeClicked = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    onSafeCLick(v)
     } 
 }
```

**Step 2 : Add extension function to make it works with any view, this will create a new SafeClickListener and delegate the work to it.**

```
    fun View.setSafeOnClickListener(onSafeClick: (View) -> Unit) {
    val safeClickListener = SafeClickListener {
        onSafeClick(it)
      }
    setOnClickListener(safeClickListener)
  }
```

**Step 3 : Now it is very easy to use it. Just replace button1.setonclicklistner with setSafeOnClickListener.**

```
settingsButton.setSafeOnClickListener {
    showSettingsScreen()
}
```

Comment: That safe my hundred of line

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the task using below code:

```
var mLastClickTime = 0L
fun isClickRecently(): Boolean {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
            return true
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        return false
}
```

And you can call this function on button click.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    if (!isClickRecently()) {
         //your task to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//its work same as setOnClickListener  
//Create Function Like this in Utils File
                        
fun View.setOnclick(listenerBlock: OnDebounceClickListener) =
  setOnClickListener(MulticlickPrevent(1000L, listenerBlock))


interface OnDebounceClickListener {
    fun onClick(view: View?)
}

class MulticlickPrevent(
    private val interval: Long,
    private val listenerBlock: OnDebounceClickListener
) : View.OnClickListener {
    private var LastClickListner = 0L

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (time - LastClickListner >= interval) {
            LastClickListner = time
            listenerBlock.onClick(v)
        }
    }
}
```

//On activity use like this

```
    myview.setOnclick(object : OnDebClickListener{
             override fun onClick(var1: View?) {
                       TODO("Do your code")
             }
     })
            
    //Or
    class MainActivity : Activity() , OnDebClickListener{
          //in onCreate method
          myview.setOnclick(this)
    }
```